# Expression Tree - Clone and Change Types of MethodCalls, Lambdas (Parameters, Return Types, Anonymous Types etc)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, expression-trees, ef-core-6.0

The below Linq query receives **entitySet** as an T type (which is of an Interface type). The generated expression tree fails to transform to Sql due to this Interface type, and hence during the expression tree query evaluation I need a way to transform all Lambdas, MethodCalls (along with their parameters, returntypes (which could be AnonymousType_of_Interface) to a supplied concrete type.

```
 IQueryable<T> GetMasterConfigsForMasterConfigExport<T>(IQueryable<T> entitySet, GetMasterConfigsForMasterConfigExportParams p)
        {
            var selectedMasterConfigIds = p.SelectedMasterConfigIds.IsNotBlank() ? p.SelectedMasterConfigIds.ConvertCSVToLong() : Enumerable.Empty<long>();
          

            var query = from masterConfig in entitySet
                        join selectedMasterConfigId in (Repository.ConvertToBigIntTable(selectedMasterConfigIds, "selectedMasterConfigId") as IQueryable<ConvertCSVToBigIntTableResult>)
                        on masterConfig.Id equals selectedMasterConfigId.Id into selectedMasterConfigIdsRS
                        from selectedMasterConfigId in selectedMasterConfigIdsRS.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where masterConfig.IsActive && selectedMasterConfigId == null
                        select masterConfig;
            return query;
        }
```

The Generated Expression tree looks like this, I would like to replace all occurrences of IMasterConfig to some other supplied concrete object somehow:

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Count(.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
        .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
            .Call System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany(
                .Extension<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryRootExpression>,
                '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[IMasterConfig,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt]]>),
                '(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`3[IMasterConfig,Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt,<>f__AnonymousType325`2[IMasterConfig,Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt]]>))
            ,
            '(.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType325`2[IMasterConfig,Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt],System.Boolean]>))
        ,
        '(.Lambda #Lambda4<System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType325`2[IMasterConfig,Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt],IMasterConfig]>))
)

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[IMasterConfig,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt]]>(IMasterConfig $masterConfig)
{
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty(.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
            .Call $__p_0.ConvertCSVToBigIntTable(
                $__List_1,
                $__Delim_2),
            '(.Lambda #Lambda5<System.Func`2[Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt,System.Boolean]>)))
}

.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`3[IMasterConfig,Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt,<>f__AnonymousType325`2[IMasterConfig,Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt]]>(
    IMasterConfig $masterConfig,
    Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt $selectedMasterConfigId) {
    .New <>f__AnonymousType325`2[IMasterConfig,Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt](
        $masterConfig,
        $selectedMasterConfigId)
}

.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType325`2[IMasterConfig,Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt],System.Boolean]>(<>f__AnonymousType325`2[IMasterConfig,Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt] $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0)
{
    ($<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.masterConfig).IsActive && $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.selectedMasterConfigId == null
}

.Lambda #Lambda4<System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType325`2[IMasterConfig,Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt],IMasterConfig]>(<>f__AnonymousType325`2[IMasterConfig,Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt] $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0)
{
    $<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.masterConfig
}

.Lambda #Lambda5<System.Func`2[Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt,System.Boolean]>(Lw.Sys.Repository.ParsedBigInt $selectedMasterConfigId)
{
    $masterConfig.Id == $selectedMasterConfigId.Id
}
```

Comment: Practically impossible with anonymous types, since they are compile time feature. You'd better find out why the compile time query expression tree contains interface instead of a concrete class implementing the interface, and correct that. Most likely you need to build it with generic method having `T : class, ISomeInterface` constraint.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the input, I kind of knew this was very difficult. Well the interfaces are there since the method signature is of T type and we are sending the actual object as Queryable<Interface> type onto the method. These interface pattern have just Getters and NOT setters (to have a layer of security).

On a side note, could you please see if there's something we can do about this query:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/71041887/514537

Comment: @IvanStoev, not sure that you are right. Anonymous classes are generic types so it can be created with new generic arguments.

Comment: Regarding the `GroupJoin`, see the code in this comment of mine on the EF Core GitHub thread https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19930#issuecomment-587476008. It might have been broken in EFC 5.0/6.0, but can be adjusted.  I really have no nervous to argue with EF Core team. The idea is to use `System.Tuple` instances instead of anonymous types.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Probably you are right :) Still believe it's better to avoid the need of such transformations. Like having constrained generic method for building `IQueryable<T>` and calling it with reflection.

Comment: @IvanStoev So does your implementation (github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19930#issuecomment-587476008.)  transforms the expression into this:

```
from userGroupId in Repository.ConvertToBigIntTable(userGroupIds, "userGroupId")
        .Where(userGroupId => documentType.Id == userGroupId.Id)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava That was the idea. And I wanted this to be done by EF Core itself.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Although it is doable but the issue also comes up as sometimes the Lambda's return type are of Anonymous type and at times it could be Anonymous[Anonymou[T]] type. How would in those cases one would get control of these expression and change the type (not just parameters but also ReturnTypes)

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava, while I think it is possible, it is time consuming task. What you have to do is to create complex ExpressionTreeVisitor which remaps properties, create generic methods with concrete types etc.  Also this one will help you in such task [ReadableExpressions.Visualizers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers)

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok I will try your code and replicate it into the Interceptor and see if I get any other issues, will come to the original question

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes I have been recently using the tool, it is very nice

Would you also take a took at this, the expected transformation was actually your answer to an earlier question that I had asked. Let me know your thoughts there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71041887/ef-core-expression-trees-groupjoin-transform-to-selectmany-dynamically

Comment: Actually we have did such transformation for some part of `linq2db` code. I cannot estimate how much time it will take to extract it from [our implementation](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/21380afa89df514e01e28946e64029766ec28485/Source/LinqToDB/Expressions/TypeMapper/TypeMapper.cs#L493).

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks for this link, I will have a look into it today!

Comment: If you just need to convert `query.GroupJoin(...).SelectMany( x=> x.Some.DefaultIfEmpty())` to `query.SelectMany( x=> x.Some.Where(...).DefaultIfEmpty())` - probably it is simpler task.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I need to convert from
`join userGroupId in Repository.ConvertToBigIntTable(userGroupIds, "userGroupId")
      on documentType.Id equals userGroupId.Id into UserGroupIds`
To:
`from userGroupId in Repository.ConvertToBigIntTable(userGroupIds, "userGroupId")
        .Where(userGroupId => documentType.Id == userGroupId.Id)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()`
that too via the interceptor (ExpressionTreeVisitor)

Comment: @IvanStoev tried your code from EFCore Github, but it fails with an InvalidOperationException:
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The query contains a projection 'masterConfig => __p_0.ConvertCSVToBigIntTable(
    List: __List_1, 
    Delim: __Delim_2)
    .Where(selectedMasterConfigId => masterConfig.Id == selectedMasterConfigId.Id)' of type 'IQueryable<ParsedBigInt>'. Collections in the final projection must be an 'IEnumerable<T>' type such as 'List<T>'. Consider using 'ToList' or some other mechanism to convert the 'IQueryable<T>' or 'IOrderedEnumerable<T>' into an 'IEnumerable<T>'.' `

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv for detailed question, please check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71041887/ef-core-expression-trees-groupjoin-transform-to-selectmany-dynamically

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava That's what I meant by they broke something in 5.0/6.0 Most likely need to include `AsEnumerable()` call somewhere or call `Enumerable` extension method instead of `Queryable`. Have no time to look at it right now. I'll take a look at your detailed question when I can (if it isn't solved meantime).

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for your input, I will also check in the meantime

Comment: @IvanStoev Working now, added AsEnumerable() after the innerQuery variable, but just wondering will this behavior impact memory. If so, then this could be very dangerous.

`var asEnumerableInnerQuery = Expression.Call(
                                typeof(Enumerable),
                                nameof(Enumerable.AsEnumerable),
                                new Type[] { innerKeySelector.Parameters[0].Type }, innerQuery);`

Comment: I don't think so. All this is for query translation, same or similar probably is used when they "expand" (replace) collection navigation properties.

Comment: Ok got it! Thanks for your help @IvanStoev, it really saved us from a great deal :)

Comment: Linq-to-sql is not Entity Framework. Please pay attention to tag descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cited by *@IvonStoev*, using the following code solves the issue in EFCore6:

```
 protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable) && node.Method.Name == nameof(Queryable.GroupJoin) && node.Arguments.Count == 5)
            {
                var outer = Visit(node.Arguments[0]);
                var inner = Visit(node.Arguments[1]);
                var outerKeySelector = Visit(node.Arguments[2]).UnwrapLambdaFromQuote();
                var innerKeySelector = Visit(node.Arguments[3]).UnwrapLambdaFromQuote();
                var resultSelector = Visit(node.Arguments[4]).UnwrapLambdaFromQuote();

                var outerKey = outerKeySelector.Body.ReplaceParameter(outerKeySelector.Parameters[0], resultSelector.Parameters[0]);
                var innerKey = innerKeySelector.Body;
                var keyMatch = MatchKeys(outerKey, innerKey);

                var innerQuery = Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Where), new[] { innerKeySelector.Parameters[0].Type },
                    inner, Expression.Lambda(keyMatch, innerKeySelector.Parameters));

                var asEnumerableInnerQuery = Expression.Call(
                                typeof(Enumerable),
                                nameof(Enumerable.AsEnumerable),
                                new Type[] { innerKeySelector.Parameters[0].Type }, innerQuery);

                var resultTypes = resultSelector.Parameters.Select(p => p.Type).ToArray();
                var tempProjectionType = typeof(Tuple<,>).MakeGenericType(resultTypes);
                var tempProjection = Expression.New(
                    tempProjectionType.GetConstructor(resultTypes),
                    new Expression[] { resultSelector.Parameters[0], asEnumerableInnerQuery },
                    tempProjectionType.GetProperty("Item1"), tempProjectionType.GetProperty("Item2"));

                var tempQuery = Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Select), new[] { outerKeySelector.Parameters[0].Type, tempProjectionType },
                    outer, Expression.Lambda(tempProjection, resultSelector.Parameters[0]));

                var tempResult = Expression.Parameter(tempProjectionType, "p");
                var projection = resultSelector.Body
                    .ReplaceParameter(resultSelector.Parameters[0], Expression.Property(tempResult, "Item1"))
                    .ReplaceParameter(resultSelector.Parameters[1], Expression.Property(tempResult, "Item2"));

                var query = Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Select), new[] { tempProjectionType, projection.Type },
                    tempQuery, Expression.Lambda(projection, tempResult));
                return query;
            }
            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
```